# Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (sequential_34/sequential_33/random_rotation_8/rotation_matrix/strided_slice:0) to a numpy array

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor

I'm new to Tensorflow and Keras. I'm making a CNN that will identify types of skin cancer. To do the same, I created a model as below:-

```
model = Sequential([layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape = (img_height,img_width,3))])
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding = "same", activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding = "same", activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), padding = "same", activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.Dense(num_classes, activation = "softmax"))
```

This model resulted in overfitting so I decided to do some data augmentation as follows:-

```
data_augmentation = Sequential()

#commented out because I faced the same error here well but thought lets avoid it for now
#data_augmentation.add(layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip("horizontal", input_shape=(img_height, img_width,3)))

data_augmentation.add(layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.2))
data_augmentation.add(layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomZoom(0.5))
```

Then I created my second model to include these augmentation layers

```
model_2 = Sequential()
model_2.add(data_augmentation)
model_2.add(layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape = (img_height,img_width,3)))
model_2.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding = "same", activation="relu"))
model_2.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model_2.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding = "same", activation="relu"))
model_2.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model_2.add(layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), padding = "same", activation="relu"))
model_2.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model_2.add(layers.Flatten())
model_2.add(layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model_2.add(layers.Dense(num_classes, activation = "softmax"))
```

Then I compiled the model

```
model_2.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Then I started the training and faced the below error

```
epochs = 20
history = model_2.fit(train_ds, validation_data=val_ds, epochs=epochs)
```

Error

```
Epoch 1/20
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-1246b4f2efac> in <module>
      1 ## Your code goes here, note: train your model for 20 epochs
----> 2 history = model_2.fit(
      3   train_ds,
      4   validation_data=val_ds,
      5   epochs=epochs

/mnt/disks/user/anaconda3/envs/cuda101/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1098                 _r=1):
   1099               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1100               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1101               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1102                 context.async_wait()

/mnt/disks/user/anaconda3/envs/cuda101/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    826     tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
    827     with trace.Trace(self._name) as tm:
--> 828       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    829       compiler = "xla" if self._experimental_compile else "nonXla"
    830       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

/mnt/disks/user/anaconda3/envs/cuda101/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    869       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    870       initializers = []
--> 871       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    872     finally:
    873       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

/mnt/disks/user/anaconda3/envs/cuda101/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    723     self._graph_deleter = FunctionDeleter(self._lifted_initializer_graph)
    724     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
--> 725         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    726             *args, **kwds))
    727 

/mnt/disks/user/anaconda3/envs/cuda101/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2967       args, kwargs = None, None
   2968     with self._lock:
-> 2969       graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2970     return graph_function
   2971 

/mnt/disks/user/anaconda3/envs/cuda101/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3359 
   3360           self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3361           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3362           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3363 

/mnt/disks/user/anaconda3/envs/cuda101/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3194     arg_names = base_arg_names + missing_arg_names
   3195     graph_function = ConcreteFunction(
-> 3196         func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
   3197             self._name,
   3198             self._python_function,

/mnt/disks/user/anaconda3/envs/cuda101/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    988         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    989 
--> 990       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    991 
    992       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

/mnt/disks/user/anaconda3/envs/cuda101/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    632             xla_context.Exit()
    633         else:
--> 634           out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    635         return out
    636 

/mnt/disks/user/anaconda3/envs/cuda101/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    975           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    976             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 977               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    978             else:
    979               raise

NotImplementedError: in user code:

    /mnt/disks/user/anaconda3/envs/cuda101/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:805 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /mnt/disks/user/anaconda3/envs/cuda101/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:795 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /mnt/disks/user/anaconda3/envs/cuda101/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1259 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /mnt/disks/user/anaconda3/envs/cuda101/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /mnt/disks/user/anaconda3/envs/cuda101/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /mnt/disks/user/anaconda3/envs/cuda101/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:788 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /mnt/disks/user/anaconda3/envs/cuda101/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:754 train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    /mnt/disks/user/anaconda3/envs/cuda101/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:1012 __call__
        outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    /mnt/disks/user/anaconda3/envs/cuda101/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py:389 call
        outputs = layer(inputs, **kwargs)
    /mnt/disks/user/anaconda3/envs/cuda101/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:1012 __call__
        outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    /mnt/disks/user/anaconda3/envs/cuda101/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py:389 call
        outputs = layer(inputs, **kwargs)
    /mnt/disks/user/anaconda3/envs/cuda101/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:1012 __call__
        outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    /mnt/disks/user/anaconda3/envs/cuda101/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/preprocessing/image_preprocessing.py:866 call
        output = control_flow_util.smart_cond(training, random_rotated_inputs,
    /mnt/disks/user/anaconda3/envs/cuda101/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/control_flow_util.py:114 smart_cond
        return smart_module.smart_cond(
    /mnt/disks/user/anaconda3/envs/cuda101/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/smart_cond.py:54 smart_cond
        return true_fn()
    /mnt/disks/user/anaconda3/envs/cuda101/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/preprocessing/image_preprocessing.py:861 random_rotated_inputs
        get_rotation_matrix(angles, img_hd, img_wd),
    /mnt/disks/user/anaconda3/envs/cuda101/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/preprocessing/image_preprocessing.py:757 get_rotation_matrix
        array_ops.zeros((num_angles, 2), dtypes.float32),
    /mnt/disks/user/anaconda3/envs/cuda101/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /mnt/disks/user/anaconda3/envs/cuda101/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py:2819 wrapped
        tensor = fun(*args, **kwargs)
    /mnt/disks/user/anaconda3/envs/cuda101/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py:2868 zeros
        output = _constant_if_small(zero, shape, dtype, name)
    /mnt/disks/user/anaconda3/envs/cuda101/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py:2804 _constant_if_small
        if np.prod(shape) < 1000:
    <__array_function__ internals>:5 prod
        
    /mnt/disks/user/anaconda3/envs/cuda101/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:3030 prod
        return _wrapreduction(a, np.multiply, 'prod', axis, dtype, out,
    /mnt/disks/user/anaconda3/envs/cuda101/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:87 _wrapreduction
        return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
    /mnt/disks/user/anaconda3/envs/cuda101/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:852 __array__
        raise NotImplementedError(

    NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (sequential_2/sequential_1/random_rotation/rotation_matrix/strided_slice:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported
```

**Please help me understand what would cause this error and what would be the correct way to add data augmentation if this isn't the expected way?**

**Note:-** I'm running this jupyter notebook on Nimblebox as I don't have a GPU to train the CNNs. So I'm not sure about the versions of the packages installed on the cloud machine. For python, it is 3.8.5.

Complete notebook available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RodlNHlXxDvMQXsZuNzkbFw-5AwVMnZX/view?usp=sharing). Please let me know if the link is not accessible or any further inputs required from my side.

Comment: You need to include the complete traceback, not just one line of it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Let me correct that and include the complete error stack

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
data_augmentation = keras.Sequential(
  [
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip("horizontal", 
                                                 input_shape=(img_height, 
                                                              img_width,
                                                              3)),
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.1),
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomZoom(0.1),
  ]
)
```

After that run your model. I will show you a code snippet of my model.

```
data_augmentation = Sequential([
                    layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(img_height, img_width,3))
])
data_augmentation.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='relu',padding = 'Same',input_shape=(180,180,3)))
data_augmentation.add(Conv2D(32,kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu',padding = 'Same',))
data_augmentation.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
data_augmentation.add(Dropout(0.25))


data_augmentation.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding = 'Same'))
data_augmentation.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding = 'Same'))
data_augmentation.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
data_augmentation.add(Dropout(0.40))


data_augmentation.add(Flatten())
data_augmentation.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
data_augmentation.add(Dropout(0.5))
data_augmentation.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
data_augmentation.summary()
```

Please note that the dropout layers are to be used when there is overfitting. If there isn't then no need to use dropouts in this scenario.